# Stored procedure to export the data to text file in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, export

I have written one stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CROSSMANUFAC IS
product          prod.product_number%TYPE;

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.enable();

delete from product;
 insert into product select unique product_number from prod p  where mynumber not in('R44','R76','R79','R20','R02',
'RY1','R71','R38','R58','RM8','RW8','R74','R73',
'R99','R72','R19','R33','RN3','R34','RP8','R22',
'R75','R01','R67','R27','R28','R57','RC5','RW7',
'RZ9','R77','R07','RW6');

commit;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_LINE ('No of rows inserted into product  '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);

delete from ABCD;

INSERT INTO ABCD(BATCH_LOT_ID,STAGE,DED_DATE,DATE_CODE)
(SELECT BATCH_LOT_ID,STAGE_FK,to_char(DED_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'),SUBSTR(DT_CD,3,4) FROM DED D WHERE D.product_number_FK IN
(SELECT * FROM product) and D.FLOG_TRANS_DT_FK =(sysdate -1));



commit;


DBMS_OUTPUT.put_LINE ('No of rows to be pushed to ABCD '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);



 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_LINE ('FUNLOC           '||'  STAGE          ' || 'SEQN_NUM' );  



commit;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_LINE ('No of rows to be pushed to ABCD  '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);    


END CROSSMANUFAC;
/
```

I want to modify this procedure in such a way that so that the data will get exported to a text file.
How to implement this functionality and where to modify in this procedure.
Thanks.

Comment: You should specify which data you want to export... In only see DELETE and INSERT there. No SELECT.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks you pointed out rightly. Actually i want to export the data of following select query :SELECT BATCH_LOT_ID,STAGE_FK,to_char(DED_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'),SUBSTR(DT_CD,3,4) FROM DED D WHERE D.product_number_FK IN
(SELECT * FROM product) and D.FLOG_TRANS_DT_FK =(sysdate -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spool commands after insertion of data in the table, then add select commands in the procedure. So it should look something like:

```
insert into product...
commit;
spool product.txt;
select * from product;
spool off;
..
..
insert into ABCD...
commit;
spool ABCD.txt;
select * from ABCD;
spool off;
..
```

Comment: while executing the query , 
spool U:\output.dat
 select * from DED_TIBCO_NXP;
spool off   i am getting the following error:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Where are you running the code, in command window or sql window, or on server prompt.

Comment: please help me in one more thing , now i want this text file to be put on some server(should automatically go after getting exported to text)

Comment: You can use winscp to transfer the file to server. To automate the process, write a batch file to run winscp and transfer files to server.

Comment: Can you help over automating the process or can you help me in writing a shell script to transfer the file